# Is mod_xsendfile not compatible with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I asked my VPS hosting provider to install mod_xsendfile. Here is what I got in response:
"I am sorry that I forgot to respond about mod_xsendfile.  My research shows that the module has not been developed in over 4 years.  Here is the developers website:

https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

I would not suggest installing an Apache modules that has not kept pace with the develpment of Apache.  In addition, the version of Apache is 2.4 on your server so it is most likely not compatible."

I would like to know, if mod_sendfile works fine on Apache 2.4. If not, are there other alternatives except `readfile` in PHP, as I want users to be able to download large files with authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this while doing other searches related to mod_xsendfile...

Anyway, mod_xsendfile is working perfectly well on Ubuntu 16.04, which has Apache version 2.4.18.

Answer (score 1):

It works also with Ubuntu 20.04, Apache 2.4.41, and php 7.4.3. It seems that the official GitHub version fixes some bugs for Apache 2.4:

https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile

It hasn't changed since 2012, though